# How to only allow exact package updates from a repository?

Tags: yum

If I have:

```
[usern@hostn yum.repos.d]$ cat google-chrome.repo 
[google-chrome]
name=google-chrome
baseurl=http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/rpm/stable/i386
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
```

...how can I ensure that there will not be incidents like (just theory): a firefox package comes out in the google chrome repo, and because (just theory again) it has a newer version then the one that's in the original repos it gets installed when updating? How could I ensure that that from the google-chrome-repos I only get the google-chrome package?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the repo file, add a line that says:

`includepkgs=google-chrome*`

This will only allow updates and installs of packages named `google-chrome*` from that repo, all other packages will be ignored. You can list multiple packages if you separate them by a space.

In a more general sense, there's no good way of handling the problem of repos having conflicting RPMs. You have to choose good repos where you trust the maintainer (I always recommend [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL)). There's a few plugins out there which might help you such as [yum-priorities](http://wiki.centos.org/PackageManagement/Yum/Priorities) and [yum-protectbase](http://wiki.centos.org/PackageManagement/Yum/ProtectBase) but I've always used the `incpludepkgs` method. It's a little more work but I can sleep better at night knowing some RPM from some repo won't blow away some other RPM from a different repo when I don't want it too.

Answer (score 1):

Install the package and turn off the repo [enabled=0]. When you are ready to update:

```
yum update
```

Then after all others have updated, turn on the repo [enabled=1].

```
yum update chrome
```

**NOTE:** just the package you want to use that repo.

Then turn off the repo again, [enabled=0].

Sounds like a pain but a simple script can do it easily. This is the best way when using an untrusted repo.

If there is an unresolvable conflict. That's what this is for:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/mylibs/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH conflicted_program
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who comes across this yum's "--enablerepo" feature is super handy for doing updates and stuff while leaving it otherwise disabled.

Install Repo

Disable the repo

`sed -i "s/enabled=1/enabled=0/g" /etc/yum.repos.d/google-chrome.repo`

Oneliner to temporarily enable repo to install chrome from that repo

`yum --enablerepo=google-chrome install google-chrome-stable`

Oneliner to temporarily enable repo to update chrome from that repo

`yum --enablerepo=google-chrome update google-chrome-stable`

You can add an alias for the update command if needed. This makes it a lot easier than having to remember the command.

`alias updatechrome="yum --enablerepo=google-chrome update google-chrome-stable"`